# Is there any way to determine or be notified whether a specific Bluetooth device (car stereo for example) is connected or not in WP8 API?

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I'm making an app that needs info on whether a certain Bluetooth device, like the car stereo, is connected or not. I'm able to retrieve the list of paired devices but no information is provided on if they are currently connected.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to try to connect to each paired device.

Comment: I have tried that and attempting to open a stream connection always results in an exception.